# Charles-proxy does not work with android 12

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I'm trying to intercept the traffic of an android application. Installed a certificate on the device, but the traffic is not decrypted.

In Charles I see an error "SSL handshake with client failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown)"

- Ssl proxy enabled to host is active.
- The certificate is installed on the smartphone.

Who faced this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: If this is your own app that you're trying to intercept traffic from, you can either use Chucker or [Requestly Android SDK](https://github.com/requestly/requestly-android-sdk). Both are free & open source.

Comment: No, its not my app. This is an application that I am testing in a ready-made form, that is, the interception is launched from a real device.

Comment: It does work with android 12 (and 13 for that matter), but you probably need to be on a debug version of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to proxy an android app depends on the network security configuration supplied at build time. The app developer specifies through an xml declaration file the configuration that the app should have when built.

Details of this can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.

It's more common for network proxying to only be available on debug versions of an app to improve security between the client app and the backend resources it uses.